# How to update the details in an array on post in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, insert-update

Although its printing the 'success' in console but i am unable to see the changes after clicking on post update.

```
User.update( { email:req.user.email }, 
  { $set: {
     "Addtasks.$[].topic": req.body.topic,
     "Addtasks.$[].words": req.body.words,
     "Addtasks.$[].keywords": req.body.keywords,
     "Addtasks.$[].website": req.body.website,
     "Addtasks.$[].otherdetails": req.body.otherdetails,
     "Addtasks.$[].exampleRadios": req.body.exampleRadios
} },function (error, success) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/status');
    console.log('success');
  }
} )
```

My json array file:

```
[
    {
        "Date" : "Mon Aug 03 2020 03:30:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
        "exampleRadios" : "option1",
        "otherdetails" : "haha great!",
        "website" : "nmbn.com",
        "keywords" : "anxiety disorders for children, anxiety disorders for adults",
        "words" : 456,
        "topic" : "How to fight anxiety",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f273771ddff850558b1e049")
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the db if it's updated? Because if you using native mongodriver, update will not return document itself, you have to use findOneAndUpdate. Second thing, findOneAndUpdate will not return updated document, but old one (dunno why they configured it like this), you have to use `options = { returnOriginal: false }` (default is true).